# unsigned char* to const TDesC8 in Symbian C++

Tags: c++, symbian, descriptor

I wanna send an unsigned char * over the Socket whereas the RSockt.Send has the following signature:

```
IMPORT_C void Send(const TDesC8 &aDesc, TUint someFlags, TRequestStatus &aStatus);
```

I tried to do it the following way but that gives me an error message:

```
Socket.Send( TPtrC8 ptr((TUint8*)charvariable), 0, iStatus);

Error #254: Type name is not allowed.
```

Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You were close but you cannot declare a variable within an expression. Here's how:

```
Socket.Send(TPtrC8((TUint8*)charvariable), 0, iStatus);
```

Note that this assumes the `unsigned char *` data is zero terminated.